# Resetting the ListNumbering in Tables in MS Word using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a model table with four columns in MS Word document with numbered list in the first column. The list starts with "**a.**" from the second row. In the first row, the table heading is placed after merging 2nd 3rd and 4th column cells.

My requirement is to copy the readily available model table in the document and create another table same structure as the model table and below the model table with one line gap between them so that no two tables are merged. Further, as the new table is created from the model table, the numbered list in the first column of the newly created table is continuing the list in the first column of the model table. I need to reset the numbering in each new table so that list-numbering starts afresh from '**a.**'.

I wrote the below-mentioned code but it is not working as expected. Pls tell me where i am going wrong and the way ahead to solve the problem.

```
Sub GenerateNewTables()
    ' Declarations
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim modelTable As Table
    Dim newTable As Table
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim startRow As Integer
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim oRange As Range
    Dim oModelRange As Range
    
    ' Set the document
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    
    ' Find the model table
    For Each tbl In doc.Tables
            Set oRange = tbl.Cell(1, 2).Range
            oRange.End = oRange.End - 1
            If oRange.Text = "Details of A1" Then
                Set modelTable = tbl
                Set oModelRange = tbl.Range
                tbl.Range.Copy
                Exit For
            End If
    Next tbl
    
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(7).ListLevels(1)
        .NumberFormat = "%1."
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleLowercaseLetter
        .NumberPosition = CentimetersToPoints(0)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = CentimetersToPoints(0.63)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        '.ResetOnHigher = 0
        .StartAt = 1
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    
    ' If the model table is found
    If Not modelTable Is Nothing Then

        oModelRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        oModelRange.InsertParagraphAfter
        oModelRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd

        ' Loop to generate new tables
        For i = 2 To 3 ' Adjust the number of tables as required
            
            oModelRange.Paste
            
            Set newTable = oModelRange.Tables(oModelRange.Tables.Count)
            newTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "Details of A" & i
            newTable.Title = "A" & i & "Info"

            newTable.Cell(newTable.Rows.Count, 1).Range.Select
            'ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(7).Name = ""
            Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
                ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(7), _
                ContinuePreviousList:=False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, _
                DefaultListBehavior:=wdWord10ListBehavior

            oModelRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
            oModelRange.InsertParagraphAfter
            oModelRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        
        Next i
    Else
        MsgBox "Model table not found."
    End If

End Sub
```

The above code is not changing the very first item in the each new table. Only the consecutive items are seen changed i.e., If the model table T1 is having the list from 'a.' to 't.', the newly created table T2 is seen with u., a., b., c. ...s. and the further new table T3 is seen witness v., a., b., c. ... s. How can i make the list in T2 with 'a.' to 't.' and T3 is also with 'a.' to 't.' using VBA and still keep the list in each table intact i.e., only one list per each table? what changes i need to make to the above code? Where am i going conceptually wrong? Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

- You code is close to finish.
- Change: select the `Cell(2, 1)` before appling `ApplyListTemplateWithLevel`

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub GenerateNewTables()
    ' Declarations
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim modelTable As Table
    Dim newTable As Table
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim startRow As Integer
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim oRange As Range
    Dim oModelRange As Range
    ' Set the document
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    ' Find the model table
    For Each tbl In doc.Tables
            Set oRange = tbl.Cell(1, 2).Range
            oRange.End = oRange.End - 1
            If oRange.Text = "Details of A1" Then
                Set modelTable = tbl
                Set oModelRange = tbl.Range
                tbl.Range.Copy
                Exit For
            End If
    Next tbl
    With ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(7).ListLevels(1)
        .NumberFormat = "%1."
        .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
        .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleLowercaseLetter
        .NumberPosition = CentimetersToPoints(0)
        .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
        .TextPosition = CentimetersToPoints(0.63)
        .TabPosition = wdUndefined
        '.ResetOnHigher = 0
        .StartAt = 1
        .LinkedStyle = ""
    End With
    ' If the model table is found
    If Not modelTable Is Nothing Then
        oModelRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        oModelRange.InsertParagraphAfter
        oModelRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        ' Loop to generate new tables
        For i = 2 To 3 ' Adjust the number of tables as required
            oModelRange.Paste
            Set newTable = oModelRange.Tables(oModelRange.Tables.Count)
            newTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "Details of A" & i
            newTable.Title = "A" & i & "Info"
            newTable.Cell(2, 1).Range.Select
            'ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(7).Name = ""
            Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
                ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(7), _
                ContinuePreviousList:=False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, _
                DefaultListBehavior:=wdWord10ListBehavior
            oModelRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
            oModelRange.InsertParagraphAfter
            oModelRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        Next i
    Else
        MsgBox "Model table not found."
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Does the first cell have list index? If so, select it before reset index.

Comment: Thanks taller. But, when i run the code with your suggestion, the first list item in each new table is continuing the previous list and the 2nd item onwards, it is resetting. 

If the model table T1 is having the list from 'a.' to 't.', the newly created table T2 is seen with u., a., b., c. ...s. and the further new table T3 is seen with v., a., b., c. ... s.


I also tried the same in new document. It is working initially and then working as mentioned above. No idea what is stopping after few initial runs.

Comment: For your question, as informed earlier, there is list number starting from 2nd row 1st column only.

The same script is behaving differenetly in different files. Not sure what is the problen with lists. I have created both the new .docx files with only one page, with one model table and one list in the first column from 2nd row.

Comment: Please edit your post to upload a screenshot of the doc which has wrong output.

Comment: Thanks taller for your reply. We can see that first item of each table is continuation of the first list as it is considered to be part of same list. screenshot [here](https://imgur.com/a/ZX7QSgQ)